# Not able to call the function from C DLL

Tags: c++, dll, load

```
//DLL Code

#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"

{


__declspec(dllexport) void DisplayHelloFromDLL()

    {
        printf("Hello from DLL !\n");
    }
}


//Program Accessing DLL

#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

typedef void (*DisplayHelloFromDLLFuncPtr)();
using namespace std;



int main()

{

    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("L:\\C_Learning\\Library\\MyLib\\Debug\\MyLib.dll");
    if (!hGetProcIDDLL)
    {

        cout << "\nCould Not The Library";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }

    else

    {
        cout << "\nDLL is Loaded";

    }

    DisplayHelloFromDLLFuncPtr LibMainEntryPoint=(DisplayHelloFromDLLFuncPtr)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "DisplayHelloFromDLL");

    if (!DisplayHelloFromDLL)
    {

        cout << "\nCould not locate the function";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cout << DisplayHelloFromDLL(); 

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    _getch();
    return 0;


}
```

1. Code executes till cout statement in else condition.
2. Receive Error while compiling for Function in DLL.
3. Error received 'DisplayHelloFromDLL': undeclared identifier
4. Ran Depends.exe which confirms about the function availability in DLL address space.
5. DLL and Sample Program is compiled with 32-bit environment.

   6.Program sole purpose is to call function C DLL and print Hello From DLL message.

   Any Suggestions ?

Comment: The function name may still be decorated. I.e under windows for a 32bits application the name should be `_DisplayHelloFromDLL` (underscore prefix). Try `DisplayHelloFromDLLFuncPtr LibMainEntryPoint=(DisplayHelloFromDLLFuncPtr)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "_DisplayHelloFromDLL");`

Comment: Thank you, however it didn't workout.

Comment: What's `DisplayHelloFromDLL` in your second code? I don't see it declared anywhere, so the code shouldn't even compile! You named your function pointer `LibMainEntryPoint`, so you should call this!

Comment: Also, feeding `void` to `cout` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: And why do you use `LoadLibrary()` at all? Without a good reason for it -- just using an import library your code links to would be a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks Frankie, Felix, yes feeding void to cout doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you for help guys.

Comment: @Felix would you be able to help with "import library" method.

Comment: @sasha this depends on your compiler, you should consult the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named the variable holding the "DisplayHelloFromDLL" function pointer as "LibMainEntryPoint":

```
DisplayHelloFromDLLFuncPtr LibMainEntryPoint=(DisplayHelloFromDLLFuncPtr)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "DisplayHelloFromDLL");
```

but then you try to use it with different name (DisplayHelloFromDLL):

```
if (!DisplayHelloFromDLL) ...
```

Be consistent with the variable names, and the code should work.
change it to:

DisplayHelloFromDLLFuncPtr **DisplayHelloFromDLL**=(DisplayHelloFromDLLFuncPtr)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "DisplayHelloFromDLL");

Comment: DisplayHelloFromDLLFuncPtr LibMainEntryPoint=(DisplayHelloFromDLLFuncPtr)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL,"_DisplayHelloFromDLL");




 if (!LibMainEntryPoint)
 {

  cout << "\ncould not locate function";
  _getch();
  return EXIT_FAILURE;

 }

Made the changes however now it is entering into if condition.

Comment: Thank you for help, issue has been fixed.